# Set categories nested path using SQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I want to generate nested category path for each category inserted.

Categories structure:

```
id
parent_id
name
```

My trigger - BEFORE -> INSERT

```
SET NEW.path = CONCAT(IFNULL((select path from categories where id = NEW.parent_id), '0'), '.', New.id)
```

NEW.id return 0?

I have no idea what i did wrong.

Comment: i use mysql. edited

Answer (score 1):

In a BEFORE trigger, `NEW.id` isn't set yet (supposing it's an auto-increment).

In an AFTER trigger, it's too late to change `NEW.path`.

You can't use a trigger for this. You have to let the INSERT finish, then subsequently do an UPDATE to change the path.